# Is it possible to use $(this) in a function called from another function?

Tags: jquery, function, this

Sorry for the question title, I know it's not very well worded, but I couldn't really explain what I'm asking in a summary.

I have a JQuery function tied to the click event of an element.  For reasons that may well be flawed (other than making more sense to me personally), within this function I am calling another function.  From the second function, I'd like to be able to call `$(this)` from the first function, but I'm not sure if it's possible, or how to do it if I can

**Example**

*JQuery function which works*

```
$('.member-div a').on("click",function(f){
    f.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('.member-div').hide();
    if($(this).hasClass('next')){
        var y = parseInt(x)+1;
    };
    if($(this).hasClass('back')){
        var y = parseInt(x)-1;
    };
    $('#section'+y).show();
});
```

*What I'm trying to do*

```
$('.member-div a').on("click",function(f){
    f.preventDefault();
    newfunc();
});

function newfunc(){
    var x = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('.member-div').hide();
    if($(this).hasClass('next')){
        var y = parseInt(x)+1;
    };
    if($(this).hasClass('back')){
        var y = parseInt(x)-1;
    };
    $('#section'+y).show();
};
```

I think I understand why the second way doesn't work (`$(this)` will not be the anchor tag from the initial function), but I am lost as to how to make it work

If I have to, or if anyone can explain that/why it is better to, I will stick with the original example that works!

Thanks

Comment: I would think it should work! it seems pretty logical to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always be careful when using the `this` as you may end up using an unexpected value depending on the context your function was called.

Instead, you should consider using a parameter:

```
$('.member-div a').on("click",function(f){
    f.preventDefault();
    newfunc($(this));
});

function newfunc(item){
    var x = item.parent('div').attr('id').slice(-1);
    $('.member-div').hide();
    if(item.hasClass('next')){
        var y = parseInt(x)+1;
    };
    if(item.hasClass('back')){
        var y = parseInt(x)-1;
    };
    $('#section'+y).show();
};
```

Comment: Not too sure if this answer is the same as the others that suggested using `newfunc(this)` and not `newfunc($(this))`, but this was the way I tired, and it works for me.  Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly the same... `this` is referring to a DOM item while `$(this)` refer to a jquery object.  Since you're always using `$(this)` (and never `this` alone), I thought it would be better to pass a jquery object as parameter instead of casting a DOM element to a jquery object every time you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass another `this`:

```
newfunc.call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the 'this' as a variable to the other function:

```
$('.member-div a').on("click",function(f){
f.preventDefault();
newfunc(this);
});
```

and then catch the 'this' by a paramter in the new function:

```
function newfunc(elem){}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the `this` reference to the function like this:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
     foo(this);
});

function foo(obj) {
     if ($(obj).hasClass("next")) {
         // ...
     }
}
```

`$(obj)` then works the same as `$(this)`.